# Interface vs abstract class when dealing with only properties

Tags: c#, abstract

This is not a technical roadblock or a challenge, I would say it's a general discussion!! If this is an inappropriate forum, please let me know I will delete it..

I have scenario where in get 10 xml from a webservice, each XML few common properties and few specific properties to that XML.

Class structure would look something similar to below

```
Public abstract class employee
{
     Public int Id {get; set;}
     Public int Name {get; set;}
 }

Public class PermanentEmployee: Employee
{
      // PermanentEmployee specific props
}

Public class ContractEmployee
{
      //Contractor​ specific properties
}
```

Given the above scenario, should employee class be abstract or it should be interface. Which is better.

I will have Only properties, No methods.

My take : I would go for abstract class as I can reuse properties, Interface won't make sense as there are no methods..

Comment: As mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask - `If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.`

Comment: It still attracted primarily options answers and should be closed.

Comment: I think this question can be asked on [http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions) - but only in cases where you present some specific scenario where you need to decide interface vs abstract class

Comment: @ManthanDavda You can also try on reddit in /r/dotnet and /r/csharp, they love those kind of discussions..

Answer (score 2):

I you want to "reuse" properties into several "child classes", I would always use an abstract class.

In case you want to just define the method signature and NOT the "logic body" of it, then use interface.

In conclusion, the source code you share with us, it would be the way I would do.

Answer (score 0):

I would define an interface IEmployee and also the abstract class.  That gives the flexibility of an interface to pass around generically, but the abstract class will be useful for those cases where you would otherwise have to repeat code (DRY etc).

```
public interface IEmployee
{
    int Id { get; set;}
    int Name { get; set;}
}

public abstract class Employee : IEmployee
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public int Name { get; set;}
}

public class PermanentEmployee: Employee
{
     // PermanentEmployee specific props
}

public class ContractEmployee : Employee
{
    //Contractor​ specific properties
}
```

Comment: Abstract class can be passed around generically too, so based on your reasons there no needs for interface. Besides interfaces are "workaround" for abstract classes in languages, which doesn't support multi-inheritance.

Comment: The example is very simplified, but at some point in the future, the abstract class may have some code (maybe some sort of pub/sub notification) that the interface may not require (you now have some IEmployee based class that doesn't need observation).  Splitting it up now will help in the future.

Comment: "Yagni"(You Aren't Gonna Need It)

Comment: Well @Fabio, I disagree.

Comment: Just made methods of abstract class virtual - and you get same behaviour . The only problem of abstract class that child classes can derived only from one base class, where with interface child classes can implement multiple interfaces